# ¿Cómo lograr que se vea un hover de imagen en iOS?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

El hover se ve bien en pantallas de escritorio, pero cuando cambio a iPhone, no se ve el hover, que debería aparecer al momento de dar un toque, pero no aparece, la imagen queda fija.

Debería mostrar una descripción y una imagen.

El sitio es: http://www.laboratorioschontalpa.com.mx/website/index.php[Laboratorios Chontalpa- Prueba]

**INDEX.PHP:**

```
<!--/*Hover 4pasos-->
<link href="css/imagehover.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--/*Escritorio-->
  <!--SeccionTop-->
    <div class="row" id="4pasos" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="pasos">
          <img src="images/Toma.jpg" alt="Toma de Muestra" class="pasosimage">
            <div class="pasosoverlay" style="background:#F6C9A8">
             <div class="pasostext"><h2>Toma de muestra</h2>
                 <p>Su muestra es tomada con calidez, utilizando material nuevo y desechable.
                    Usando un código de barras para la identificación de su muestra.</p><br>
                    <img src="images/img-toma-hover.png" class="hidden-xs" alt="Toma de Muestra">
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="pasos">
          <img src="images/Traslado.jpg" alt="Traslado de Muestra" class="pasosimage">
    <div class="pasosoverlay" style="background: #BAE7FF">
     <div class="pasostext"><h2>Traslado de muestra</h2>
        <p>Su muestra es transportada de manera segura y confiable, en unidades propias;
                    con un método de refrigeración controlado.</p><br>

               <img src="images/img-traslado-hover.png" class="hidden-xs" alt="Traslado de Muestra">
              </div>
         </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="pasos">
          <img src="images/Analisis.jpg" alt="Analisis de muestra" class="pasosimage">
            <div class="pasosoverlay" style="background:#BAE7FF">
             <div class="pasostext"><h2>Análisis de muestra</h2>
                 <p>La muestra se analiza con equipos de tecnología avanzada, conectados a un servidor; cumpliendo con controles de calidad.</p><br>
                <img src="images/img-analisis-hover.png" class="hidden-xs" alt="Analisis de muestra">
                </div>
         </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="pasos">
          <img src="images/Entrega.jpg" alt="Entrega de Resultados" class="pasosimage">
            <div class="pasosoverlay" style="background:#B1F3CF">
             <div class="pasostext"><h2>Entrega de Resultados</h2>
                 <p>Del laboratorio central se envían los resultados de manera confidencial vía electrónica, a través de un servidor propio, obteniendo: <i>¡Resultados seguros!</i></p><br />
                <img src="images/img-entrega-hover.png" class="hidden-xs" alt="Entrega de resultados">
                </div>
         </div>
          </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

**pasos.CSS:**

```
   @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

 .pasos {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

 .pasosimage {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;}

 .pasosoverlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #B5FFD7;}

 .pasos:hover .pasosoverlay {
  opacity: 1;}

.pasostext {
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  align-content: center;
  transform: translate(-15%, -15%, -15%, -15%);
  transform-ms-transform: translate(-20%, -20%);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 120%;}
```

Comment: que versión de iOS y modelo de iPhone?

Comment: Lo estoy probando en iPhone 5s la versión 11.4.1

Comment: hola @RebecaLopezCobarrubias cuando una pregunta acepta una respuesta y la marca como válida, se sobre entiende que ya se resolvió por lo cual no es necesario que les pongas en el título la palabra resuelto, por favor revisa el [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrías intentarlo con jquery para que interprete el evento y pueda ser mas preciso, te adjunto el fiddle para que lo puedas comprobar https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/703863/  si expira te adjunto la muestra ejecutable , saludos!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".pasos").hover(function(){
    //Cuando haces "hover" en ios
    $(".pasosoverlay").css({"opacity":"1"});
  }, function(){
    //Cuando haces "hover off" en ios
     $(".pasosoverlay").css({"opacity":"0"});
 })
});
```

```css
.pasosoverlay{ opacity:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="pasos">
          <img src="images/Entrega.jpg" alt="Entrega de Resultados" class="pasosimage">
            <div class="pasosoverlay" style="background:#B1F3CF">
             <div class="pasostext"><h2>Entrega de Resultados</h2>
                 <p>Del laboratorio central se envían los resultados de manera confidencial vía electrónica, a través de un servidor propio, obteniendo: <i>¡Resultados seguros!</i></p><br />
                <img src="images/img-entrega-hover.png" class="hidden-xs" alt="Entrega de resultados">
                </div>
         </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Me funciona, pero ahora el hover se hace al mismo tiempo en las cuatro secciones, y después no puedo salir del hover... la verdad no sé casi nada de jQuery, pero intenté asignarle un id a casa imagen, pero no funciona.

Comment: habría que usar un `$(this).find(".pasosoverlay")` dentro del hover para que no modifique todas las classes sino solo la hija